# Error when checking the kubernetes version

Tags: kubernetes

I am quite new to kubernetes and when i check the kubernetes version with kubectl version I am getting the following error.

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.0", GitCommit:"6e937839ac04a38cac63e6a7a306c5d035fe7b0a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-09-28T22:57:57Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
    Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Can you please help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check if Kubernetes is working or not. It is showing local kubernetes is died. Try to restart the Kubernetes service.

Comment: Some more information would be helpful; how have you created the Kubernetes Cluster? Where is it running? Finally, the error is encountered if kubectl is not properly configured with a `kubeconfig` that points to an actual running Kubernetes API server.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have setup kubernetes via kubeadm. Please verify if your kubernetes is running or not.

```
systemctl restart kubeadm
```

After that check if port is listening or not

```
netstat -an | grep :6443
```